# Return 0 value of SUM function for all rows in left table

Tags: postgresql

forgive the probably inane question.

I am using the following where I want to return a value for every salesman even if the spend is zero. How do I achieve this ?

```
SELECT
  CAST(coalesce(customer.salesman, '0') AS integer) as Salesman,
  Sum(sophead.order_value) AS "Quote Value"
FROM
  customer
  INNER JOIN sophead ON sophead.inv_account = customer.account
WHERE
  customer.company = 2 AND
  Extract(MONTH FROM sophead.order_date) = Extract(MONTH FROM Now()) AND
  Extract(YEAR FROM sophead.order_date) = Extract(YEAR FROM Now()) AND
  sophead.order_type = 'Q' AND
  sophead.salesman IN ('21','22','25','28','29','76')
GROUP BY
  customer.salesman
ORDER BY
  customer.salesman
```

Comment: Hi, please show your data (as copyable text, please no images) and expected output. We cannot help you if we don't see your data.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Where you get the spend ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use LEFT JOIN and COALESCE to ensure you show 0 if no sales:

```
SELECT
  CAST(coalesce(customer.salesman, '0') AS integer) as Salesman,
  COALESCE(Sum(sophead.order_value), 0) AS "Quote Value"
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN sophead 
ON sophead.inv_account = customer.account
AND Extract(MONTH FROM sophead.order_date) = Extract(MONTH FROM Now()) 
AND Extract(YEAR FROM sophead.order_date) = Extract(YEAR FROM Now())
AND sophead.salesman IN ('21','22','25','28','29','76')
WHERE customer.company = 2 
  AND sophead.order_type = 'Q' 
GROUP BY
  customer.salesman
ORDER BY
  customer.salesman
```

Comment: This is the output I'm getting. However, I am missing salesman 28 and 76 who have a value of zero. If I remove all the WHERE statements I get a result for all salesman. As soon as I insert the WHERE clause I get the result below.

salesman Quote Value 
21 7277.71
22 11385.32
25 23168.47
29 9289.36

Comment: I have amended the query because you are linking with EXTRACT function in the WHERE clause, so, this is like an INNER JOIN. In any case, clause AND sophead.salesman IN ('21','22','25','28','29','76') is suspicious as... why do you want only customers but filtering by sophead? It will show records that contain one of the filtered values in any case...